# Cookie wont create with app.use(express.static('public')) and Cookie-parser

Tags: javascript, express, cookies, socket.io

I have an amature project and basicly and amature problem

```
const express = require('express');
const { createServer } = require('node:http');
const { Server } = require('socket.io');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')


const app = express();
const server = createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server);

const Key = '05fee5dd86bca59b3ab9dc1d4f2a81da806edc8d8bb04277187cb7efed51fc4a7a5450037d2689e8b40617ac3d0d70ed9d7666c0cd82c19336b5cb7c23ad3f30'

//server up

//using public library of files
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(express.static('C:/Users/user/kasyno/client'))

//main unlogged page
app.get('/',(req, res) => {
  res.cookie('Cookie', 'value')
  res.sendFile('C:/Users/user/kasyno/client/index.html')
  
});

//listening to a port
server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('server running at http://localhost:3000');
});


//IO listening to connection
io.on('connection', socket =>{
  console.log('user has joined');


  //listening to joinbuton click event
  socket.on('JoinRoom', (nickname,password) =>{

    
    if(password == casinoPassword){
      
      //emiting server sesponse
      socket.emit('Join', true)
      AddClient(socket.id,nickname,1000)
    

      console.log('Logged!');
      console.log(casinoRoom)

    }else if(password!= casinoPassword){
      //emiting server sesponse
      socket.emit('Join', false)
    }  
  })
})  

function AddClient(id,nick,points){
  var Client = {nick:undefined, points:undefined}
  casinoRoom[id] = {nick:nick,points:points}
 
}


const casinoRoom = {}
const casinoPassword = "1234"
```

basicly, cookie doesnt show up until i comment out the  `app.use(express.static('C:/Users/user/kasyno/client'))` line.

In the client folder i have .html and .js files to access in the server.

Do somebody know what is causing this and how to fix it?

Thanks

Awnser what is causing a problem

Comment: You have two handlers for the same path `/`. Which one should be triggered? `app.use(express.static('C:/Users/user/kasyno/client'))` or `app.get('/',(req, res) => {`?

Comment: `app.use(express.static('C:/Users/user/kasyno/client'))` should, because other way when i will only send `index.html` script attached to that file wont ever trigger

Comment: So what should do now